# How can I create a unique link that auto-fills a form in php?

Tags: php, html, sql, url, phpmyadmin

I have a .php web form that I would like to append a string from a sql database to the url that can be clicked that is associated with the sql string. Any help would be greatly appreciated! For example, twitter.com/mrgoolboy. The username appended to the url associates content on that page with the data relating to the username.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: Yes!  For example, https://twitter.com/mrgoolboy. The username appended to the url associates content on that page with the data relating to the username! I'll add this example to my question as well.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use a query string value?  How to make "pretty URLs" which have values without the query string format?  Something else?  The question is very broad and unclear as it is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm just wondering how to create a unique link that is associated with a variable from a database. I'm not worried about how it looks. This may be very simple, but I'm new to php and lost on the concept.

Comment: Do you want something like this yourpage.php?string=Hsjgsiejgdkskgsksgdjfojdgshksghdkkaagsjjshskgeu

Comment: So you're talking about twitter.com/mrgoolboy, but we can explain how it works for a url looking like twitter.com/user.php?name=mrgoolboy right?

Comment: Yes! Something like that would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 4 steps to achieve that.

- Create text field in database table `permalink`
- Ask to user to set his/her username or permalink `twitter.com/@naveedramzan` here `naveedramzan` is permalink. Here you can add your auto-fill form for URL.
- Update `.htaccess` to parse permalink and open relevant file
- In database query, instead of filter record based on `id`, you need to do filter based on `permalink` field

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot, very helpful!

Comment: Thanks, you may up vote once you will be done and executed.